# Trying to plot two functions with tikzpicture where one of the them is a parabola

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the following two equations:
y = x
4x + y^2 = 12

The second one is a parabola. So, I need to solve for y. When I do that, I have a square root. So I break
the second equation into two equations. I then use the following LaTex code to generate my plot. However, the bottom half of my parabola does not show up. I am hoping somebody can tell me why.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin = -12, xmax = 3,
ymin = -21, ymax = 12,
]
\addplot [
domain=-15:5, blue,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {x};
\addplot [
domain=-20:3, blue,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {sqrt(12-4*x)};
\addplot [
domain=3:20, blue,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {-sqrt(4*x-12)};
\end{axis}
```

Comment: You can plot it as `\addplot ({(12-y^2)/4},{y});` I think.

Comment: @C.F.G I tired what you suggested but it did not work. Here is the error message: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots ex [samples y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain. \addplot ({(12-y^2)/4},{y});
running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} into your preamble.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in signs and domain -remember to add compilable code to your question. Here is code, with colors to differentiate the plots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [
domain=-20:3, red,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {x};
\addplot [
domain=-20:3, green,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {sqrt(12-4*x)};
\addplot [
domain=-20:3, blue,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] {-sqrt(12-4*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with line and two half parabolas]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
domain=-5:5, blue,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
] ({(12-x^2)/4},{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]